# Have social accounting matrices and input output models fallen out of fashion? if so, why?

Tags: macroeconomics, statistics, input-output

My perception may be uninformed but 'worldwide' I believe collection of official data on input output tables of economies dont seem to be keeping up with the times. Im aware that compilation of such data sets is difficult hence the large time gaps between releases but I would think that 5 years or so would suffice. examples of countries where such data are up to date would be much appreciated

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. It might be me, but your question sounds rather broad, and a bit unclear. Could you maybe provide examples of the kind of matrices you are thinking of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

National Statistical Institutes do still compile IO tables (see http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/esa-supply-use-input-tables for EU versions, although these are 5-yearly as well).  They're generally more interested in producing the Supply and Use tables (which are then transformed into input-output tables) due to their usefulness in balancing the 3 measures of GDP.

There are also attempts by groups such as WIOD to produce world input-output databases.

Part of the reason for the long delay in producing IO tables following the reference year is simply the very large quantity of data required to compile them, plus the time taken to investigate and resolve issues highlighted by the confrontation of the many various data sources.

Social accounting matrices are also still produced, and frequently used to calibrate things like CGE models rather than being used directly via SAM multipliers.

Most of the work in input-output modeling I see these days relates to environmental modeling, but this is by no means exclusive. The International Input-Output Association (www.iioa.org) runs a publication called the Journal of Economic Systems Research which can point you at some current work.

The UN are also working on a handbook foot IO and extensions due some time this year, which aims to provide a range of options for countries with smaller or less well established statistical institutions to construct tables, as well as more established ones.